# Как узнать запущено ли приложение на телефоне

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Я разрабатываю приложение. Делаю его на Cordova, но если подскажите решение для нативного кода - буду благодарен.

Суть задачи: надо знать когда приложение полностью закрывается. Или по другому: надо знать, запущено ли приложение у пользователя или нет.

Думал решить эту задачу обычной отправкой запросов на сервер по интервалу, но когда приложение сворачивается - останавливается отправка запросов.

Подскажите, как это можно решить

Comment: Смутно припоминаю, что если нужно неавторизованные данные на сервер отсылать из фона (когда приложение свернуто), то вроде как-то не сложно этот механизм реализуется. Проблемы начинаются, если нужно, чтобы пользователь был авторизован.

Comment: у меня в локальную память сохраняется идентификатор. и мне нужно что бы каждые, скажем, 30 секунд на сервер отправлялся "пинг", что приложение запущено

Comment: Запускаете сервис, устанавливайте приемник при получении которого отсылаете что-то на сервер, а приложение посылает раз в n секунд сообщение для приемника.

Comment: можете как то подробнее обяснить или дать ссылку на документацию по этому